# Java button event calls method in another class

Tags: java, swing, static-methods

I am getting an error for "non static method coSearchReturn(String[]) cannot be referenced from a static context."

I've read a few articles on this error and can't seem to apply them to my situation.  Not that my situation is special, just my limited experience!  What I have is a jTable where the user selects a row in the table and I pass the table values to another form in a different class when the user clicks the OK button.  I created a method in the target form to handle the data and I'm trying to call that method from the button event.  From what I've read, I need to instantiate it to call it but I can't figure out where/how.

Here is the button event code.  I am getting the selected row from the table, using the first value in the row to reference back to the ArrayList that the table was built from.  The arraylist contains more data that is displayed in the table and I need all of it.  I want to send the correct value from the arraylist to the form in the target method/class.

```
   private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int rowNum = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String coNum = jTable1.getValueAt(rowNum,0).toString();
    String[] text;

    int x = coSearchResults.size();
    for (int temp = 0; temp < x; temp++){
        text = coSearchResults.get(temp).split("\\|");
            //inner loop is for each column, in the row
            for (String y : text ){
            if (y.equals(coNum))  {
                CheckIn_Search.coSearchReturn(text);
            }
            }
    }         

    dispose();
}
```

The target method coSearchResults is in a different class, CheckIn-Search.  Right now, the code just switches panels in the jFrame, but eventually will populate a form I am creating using the jPanel.

```
    public void coSearchReturn(String[] results){
    jPanel1.setVisible(false);
    jPanel3.setVisible(true);
}
```

What I THINK I need to do is instantiate coSeachReturn but can't get my head around where/how.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Really?  Basically, `CheckIn_Search` is the actually class, but the method is not `static` and requires instance of the class before you can call it.  Instead of trying to call the method via the class, pass a instance of the class to the caller and use it instead

Comment: You can't call something that doesn't exist. Since you haven't created an object, the non-static method doesn't exist yet. A static method (by definition) always exists.

Comment: both your comments are in line with what I have read, I'm just having issues applying it.  Can you show me where to create the object and call it?  It should be simple but i'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create object inside your conditon or as a class field, so you can use your method:

```
if (y.equals(coNum))  {
     CheckIn_Search checkIn_Search = new CheckIn_Search();
     checkIn_Search.coSearchReturn(text);
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I would have swore I tried this but obviously not.  thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an instance of `CheckIn_Search` to the class instance containing the `btnOKActionPerformed` method, for instance during the constructor. You can then store the reference in a field. Then you can call `checkInSearch.coSearchReturn(text)` if `checkInSearch` is the name of that field.

If no instance of `CheckIn_Search` exists yet, then call `new CheckIn_Search().coSearchReturn(text)` (considering a no-argument constructor). But I presume it already exists because of the `jPanel1` and `jPanel3` fields.